# Apple's Mail app shows Exchange account offline with Outlook

Tags: exchange, apple-mail, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have been using Apple's Mail app to check my Exchange account. I fired up Outlook on the same machine and added the same Exchange account. Now, Mail always shows the Exchange account as "currently offline" ('!' icon).

When I try to take the account online, it the icon spins for a second and returns to the offline state -- no emails are sent or received. Any thoughts about what the conflict might be?

Comment: What is the format you are using for your credentials? How are you entering them exactly? Please post back (sanitized, of course), how your put in the URL, domain\user or username@domain.com, and if there are any checkboxes for SSL.

Comment: I followed the Mac mail instructions provided by my institution, which worked until I ran Outlook concurrently. I enter my username without the domain (tried with, too). I add the internal & external server as servername.example.com. I am using SSL but have tried without.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try entering in this format, which I have used for other Apple products:

```
URL: domain.com:443
user: user@domain.com
password
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. That solution didn't work in this case, but Mail was able to re-autodetect the settings today.

Comment: Glad the auto-discover kicked in. Keep this solution though if you ever need to connect and iPhone.